# Using wildcard as a value

Tags: css, sass

Is there a way to use wildcard to write all these twenty rules as one:

```
.margin-bottom-1rem {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.margin-bottom-2rem {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

...

.margin-bottom-20rem {
  margin-bottom: 20rem;
}
```

I found many resources about capturing all the class names, but none about using a part of the captured name as a value. If this is not possible with wildcards, is there another workaround to avoid these duplicated rules?

Comment: Use this selector `*[class^="margin-bottom-"]` to select the elements. Note: the priority is low. It is not possible to extract the value `..rem` of the classname. Use Javascript for this.

Comment: No. Even with SCSS/LESS etc, the CSS will still **compile** to the full set of rules. a Pre-processor just makes it easier to write the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SCSS

```
$sizes: 1rem, 2rem, 5rem, 10rem, 20rem;

@each $size in $sizes {
  .margin-bottom-#{$size} {
    margin-bottom: $size;
  }
}
```

## SASS

```
$sizes: 1rem, 2rem, 5rem, 10rem, 20rem

@each $size in $sizes
  .margin-bottom-#{$size}
    margin-bottom: $size
```

Both produce this:

```
.margin-bottom-1rem {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.margin-bottom-2rem {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.margin-bottom-5rem {
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
}

.margin-bottom-10rem {
  margin-bottom: 10rem;
}

.margin-bottom-20rem {
  margin-bottom: 20rem;
}
```

#### Do something for every element

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/lists#do-something-for-every-element

Comment: Ah, loops! https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/for

Comment: Did this answer your question?